# Concern about bundle size, warning with dynamic Material-UI icons in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I really like **Material UI** for React, pretty straightforward, easy to use. So I decided to build one of my projects with that where I need to use dynamic icons.

So I found a nice workaround for this scenario which is the following:

```
interface Props {
    iconName: string,
}

const MaterialIcon = ({iconName}:Props) => {
    const resolved = require(`@material-ui/icons/${iconName}`).default;
    return React.createElement(resolved);
}
```

Usage in my component:

```
<Avatar aria-label="Storage">
    <MaterialIcon iconName={'Storage'} />
</Avatar>

<Avatar aria-label="Web">
    <MaterialIcon iconName={'Web'} />
</Avatar>
```

The solution works like charm just like the below example shows:

[image]

***Questions and concerns***

**1. There is one annoying warning message on the terminal**

> ./node_modules/@material-ui/icons/index.d.ts 4:5
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:5)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>   | import SvgIcon from '@material-ui/core/SvgIcon';
>   |
>   type SvgIconComponent = typeof SvgIcon;
>   |
>   | export const AccessAlarm: SvgIconComponent;

Is there any way to get rid of this warning message?

**2. Changed bundle size**

The mentioned solution dramatically changes the bundle size of the application.

Let's say in the whole application I would use only 5-10 icons approximately. I am not pretty convinced about the above solution, maybe it is worth to include them somehow differently.

Any thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? Having the same dilemma now myself.

Comment: @Terry Not really, I ended up importing each icons separately which solves the bundle size issue but not really a dynamic solution at this point.

Comment: Any solution to this @norbitrial ?

Comment: @KaleemElahi I assume this warning message happened intentionally, so probably we should avoid this type of solutions. Briefly I don't have any solution for this yet, it still works as I mentioned in my earlier comment, importing each icons separately.

Comment: @norbitrial maybe I am a bit late but you can use the https://icomoon.io/ in your application